# How to return the value of a super variable?

Tags: java, super

I'm writing  program that demonstrates the use of inheritance and I have created a variable using the super() keyword. I am now trying to place the value of that variable into a new method that calls it so that I can call that method in my main method to use its value within other classes.

Here is the relevant code:

**Food class (super class)**

```
public class Food {

    //field that stores the name of the food
    public String name; 
    //constructor that takes the name of the food as an argument
    public Food(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Meat class (sub class with super keyword)**

```
public class Meat extends Food 
{
public Meat() {
    super("Meat");
}
    public String getName() {
        return //get super() value??;
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
     Wolf wolfExample = new Wolf();
     Meat meatExample = new Meat();  
     System.out.println("************Wolf\"************");
     System.out.println("Wolves eat " + meatExample.getName());
    }
 }
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why are you overriding `getName` at all when the inherited implementation works fine?

Comment: I thnink your problem is a misunderstanding of inheritance http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't override  `public String getName()` in `Meat` class.
The inheritance allows to inherit public and protected methods of `Food` in all subclasses of `Food`, therefore in `Meat`.

So `Meat` which IS a `Food` has by definition this behavior :

```
 public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

which returns the `name` field stored in the parent class.

Overriding a method in subclass to write exactly the same code than in the parent method is useless and should not be done because it is misleading. A person which reads the code will wonder : why having overrided the method in the child class if it does the same thing than the parent class ?

---

**Edit**

Besides, if you want to access a field declared in a super class from a subclass, you should  :

- provide a public getter in the super class if the field is private. Here :

  `public String getName() {
        return name;
    }`
- use directly the field in the subclass if the field has the protected modifier.

As a general rule, you should avoid declaring instance fields with the modifier public because by default properties of a object should be protected and you should provide methods to modify the field only if needed.

So, declaring your Food class like that seems more suitable :

```
public class Food {

    //field that stores the name of the food
    private String name; 
    //constructor that takes the name of the food as an argument
    public Food(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

In your `Meat` class, imagine you would like to add an additional information in the string returned by `getName()`, you could override it and why not using the field from the super class :

```
public class Meat extends Food {
   public Meat() {
     super("Meat");
   }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
      return super.getName + "(but don't abuse it)";
   }
}
```

Here overriding the method is helpful because the behavior of the method in the child class differs from which one definedin the super class.

Answer (score 6):

You could just do

```
public String getName() {
   return super.getName();
}
```

Although you don't even need to override the method in the first place, because you declared the field *name* in `super` class to be `public` which means it can be accessed from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Simply write:

```
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

This is because when searching for a variable named `name`, Java proceeds in this order:

1. Local variables (none)
2. Current class's fields (none)
3. Superclass's fields (found)
4. Super-super-class's fields (etc.)

---

However, you didn't need to override `getName()` in the subclass in the first place. If you didn't define it, then it would inherit the superclass's implementation, which corresponds exactly to the behavior you wanted. Thus you were doing extra work for no gain.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers showed you how to do what you want.

But you should't do it (in real life projects)!

The most important principle in object oriented programming is **encapsulation** (aka *information hiding*). This means that the internal structure of a class should not be visible or accessible to the outside.
Therefore all member variables should be private.

Also you should avoid setter/getter methods since they just redirect the access. (except the class is a DTO without any logic of its own).

Answer (score -1):

Since food class has the method getName declared as public do

```
public String getName() {
    return super.getName();
}
```